# How to get a signal when the geometry to a line in QGIS is changed

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am working on a plugin in QGIS and want to get a signal when the geometry to a feature(in this case a polyline) in my layer is changed. For example if I use the node tool to drag one of the nodes.

In the qgis-api-documantion(http://qgis.osgeo.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html) i see that the line:
`void geometryChanged (QgsFeatureId fid, QgsGeometry &geom)` is listed under signals.

So I used this command: 
`QObject.connect(self.iface.activeLayer(),SIGNAL("geometryChanged(QgsFeatureId,     QgsGeometry)"),self.changedGeometry)`

I have a method called changedGeometry:

```
def changedGeometry(self, intValue, qgsGeom):
    QMessageBox.information(self.iface.mainWindow(),"Message", "Changed geometry. intValue: " + str(intValue) + "qgsGeom: " + str(qgsGeom))
```

When executed I get this error:

```
TypeError: C++ type 'QgsFeatureId' is not supported as a slot argument type
```

I have also tried `QObject.connect(self.iface.activeLayer(),SIGNAL("geometryChanged(int, QgsGeometry)"),self.changedGeometry)`.

Then the program do not crash, but I don't get the message about changed geometry

I am using QGIS version 1.8.0-Lisboa. Compiled against Qt 4.7.1 and these

```
import statements are in the top:                                                             
from PyQt4.QtCore import *    
from PyQt4.QtGui import *   
from qgis.core import *   
from qgis.gui import *
```

Edit:
I tried using qint64 instead QgsFeatureId, but it still don't work.

`QObject.connect(self.iface.activeLayer(),SIGNAL("geometryChanged(qint64,QgsGeometry)"),self.changedGeometry)`

Edit2:
I also tried using the new style of connecting signals and slots. 
`self.iface.activeLayer().geometryChanged.connect(self.changedGeometry)`
But it gave me this error message:

TypeError: connect() failed between geometryChanged(qint64,QgsGeometry) and unislot()

Comment: Could you actually report how you got it to work please ? I'm having a similar problem with featureDeleted, and need to stay with stable build 1.8 for now.
Thanks.

Comment: They probably solved it by using the correct signature of the method in the signal text, ie "QgsFeatureId, QgsGeometry &". The missing & is important. See here the C++ signature of the method: http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html. Not sure why QgsFeatureId would not work, but even if QgsFeautreId was fixed, the 2nd argument is still wrong in the text of this post.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. That was a bug in the SIP bindings.  Fixed in [commit:32978fb4](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/repository/revisions/32978fb4e9a6b115bed3245a90c4c038ed3fb04c).  Apparently the names of the signals have to match in python and C++ - so `qint64` doesn't work as expected.

In Windows there are still some issues, though. See bug [#6573](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6573)

Comment: I tried using qint64, but it still don't work.

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work with the old style. But with the new style, I still get a error message. I might have done something wrong. It is not important to me since the old style works, but I thought you might want to know. 
`self.iface.activeLayer().geometryChanged.connect(self.geomChanged)` gave this error: TypeError: connect() failed between geometryChanged(QgsFeatureId,QgsGeometry) and unislot()